# Slimit python minifier strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, python, minify

I am trying to minify some javascript with the Python 'slimit' package.

```
import slimit
slimit.minify('[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]')
```

runs fine and returns '[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]'

```
import slimit
slimit.minify('[01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08]')
```

gives an error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token (NUMBER, '8') at 1:23 between
>   LexToken(NUMBER,'0',1,22) and LexToken(RBRACKET,']',1,24)

The strange thing is that minifying the string [01,02,03,04,05,06,07] works ok.

Slimit only returns an error when minifying 8 or more zero padded integers in an array.

Comment: Someone just added an answer and then deleted it!?

The answer was that a leading zero indicates an octal number, therefore 08 and 09 are invalid numbers.
This is true in Python, however Javascript allows 08 and 09, converting them to decimal 8 and 9.
Perhaps the Slimit package should handle numbers to replicate the Javascript rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is down to the lexer used by slimit. Numbers starting with "0" (but not "0x") are treated as octal integers. The sequence "08" therefore ends up as 2 separate tokens ("0", "8") hence the "Unexpected Token" error.

Note the following:

```
>>> from slimit import lexer
>>> L = Lexer()
>>> L.input("02")
>>> L.token() 
LexToken(NUMBER,'02',1,0)
>>> L.input("08")
>>> L.token()  
LexToken(NUMBER,'0',1,0)
>>> L.token()
LexToken(NUMBER,'8',1,1)
```

Looking a [the source](https://github.com/rspivak/slimit/blob/4679aa25f1fcc690473e750fa97b6e5e02a35cc8/src/slimit/lexer.py#L346) for the lexer, we see the regex used to identify numbers:

```
t_NUMBER = r"""
(?:
    0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+              # hex_integer_literal
 |  0[0-7]+                        # or octal_integer_literal (spec B.1.1)
 |  (?:                            # or decimal_literal
        (?:0|[1-9][0-9]*)          # decimal_integer_literal
        \.                         # dot
        [0-9]*                     # decimal_digits_opt
        (?:[eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?       # exponent_part_opt
     |
        \.                         # dot
        [0-9]+                     # decimal_digits
        (?:[eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?       # exponent_part_opt
     |
        (?:0|[1-9][0-9]*)          # decimal_integer_literal
        (?:[eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?       # exponent_part_opt
     )
)
"""
```

The question of whether slimit should support octal representations or treat them as plain base-10 integers is open to debate.

The JSON spec explicitly forbids octal forms of numbers and some tools would flag that up as invalid JSON (try [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/)). From [RFC 4627 (2.4. Numbers)](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt?number=4627):

> Octal and hex forms are not allowed.  Leading zeros are not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Though I am not sure is it relative or not.

This might [useful](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) (the problem about parseInt in javascript)

If we just simply use

```
some_number = parseInt(08);
```

It return 0.(in some browser)

Seems json is not support to decode the number start with 0 either.

Comment: That's why you should always provide a radix as the second parameter of `parseInt`.